# How do I triangularise a netlist?

Tags: circuits, boolean-algebra

I have a circuit that is represented as a netlist (specifically, an and-inverter graph).  The desired outputs of this circuit are known.  We can assume that some combination of the primary inputs *will* result in the desired outputs.  If it makes it easier, you can assume that there's only one combination of inputs that will give me the desired output.  How do I find those inputs?

Each output for the netlist can be represented as a combinatorial boolean equation, so I was tempted to convert each output, triangularise, and solve to obtain the suitable primary inputs.  However, converting the netlist to equation-form (i.e. a similar operation to *unfolding* it) incurs a prohibitive space cost.  Is there a way to "triangularise" the circuit so that I can find suitable primary inputs?  Or, alternatively, can anyone recommend a way to achieve the goal of finding suitable primary inputs?

Comment: Looks like a generalization of SAT and SAT itself is NP-complete.  So I'll suggest looking at heuristics used by SAT solvers.